# Add a Value from drop down to a session variable and retrieve it in Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have been working with the symfony framework and I have the following issue.
I have a dropdown that generates employee details.
I have created a drop down that populate the a number according to the employee.
I want that number to be add in to a session and I want to retrieve it where ever I want.
Please help me with this matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a value to the session from a controller:

```
$phoneNumber = //....;
$session = this->container->get('session');
$session->set('phoneNumber', $phoneNumber);
```

You can then retrieve the phone number like this:

```
$session->get('phoneNumber');
```

There is an entire chapter about session management [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/sessions.html).